# What does パー mean by itself?

Tags: words, katakana

In the anime "Fairy Tail", I came across the line 「ってか　お色気代　１０００ジュエル　パーだわ　これ」 which the translator subtitled as "By the way, I spent the 1000 jewels I saved by using my sexual appeal for this..." I was wondering what パー means here, since I've never seen it by itself before and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, パー means "completely gone" or "entirely wasted", often with the nuance that the thing that is completely gone is something that you worked hard to get. [デジタル大辞泉 offers the following definition](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/172848/m0u/%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC/):

> ２ 持っていた金品がすっかりなくなること。それまで苦労したことが全くむだになること。また、そのさま。

There is also a definition in EDICT, but you have to search for ぱあ or パア in order for it to show up, which is probably why you couldn't find it:

> ぱあ (n,adj-na) (2) disappearing completely

I have mostly seen this used as 何々が**パーだ** or 何々が**パーになる**. EDICT seems to indicate that it can be used as a な-adjective, but I have never seen it used that way.

Comment: Ahh thanks, this helps. I was aware that often things won't come up in dictionaries when entered in katakana instead of hiragana, yet somehow I still missed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ColeFudge Right, this is something to be aware of particularly in katakana words that use the long vowel ー, since online dictionaries will sometimes normalize ー to あいうえお instead (スーパー to すうぱあ, トースト to とおすと, etc.)